# Microbit music / scroll output corrupting memory?

Tags: bbc-microbit

My son and I are trying to implement one of the fun-science.org microbit tutorials - building a "tug of war" game.  Essentially, 10 presses on button A moves the sprite closer to that button and the same applies on button B.  When you hit the edge of the screen, music plays and a message is scrolled on the screen before the game restarts.

We've got it fully working, but once the game has been won, it doesn't seem to reset properly.  It works fine on the simulator, but not on the physical device (a microbit 2).

Once the game is won, the behaviour is erratic.  It usually puts the sprite back in the middle, sometimes not, but frequently, one button doesn't work in the next game.  Occasionally both stop working.  In every situation, a restart fixes things.

Is there something wrong with the code?  I've wondered whether the music / message is corrupting something and I need to put a wait in for it to complete.  I've re-downloaded the hex file and re-flashed the microbit several times, so I think I've eliminated a corrupt code file.

Javascript version of code shown below, but it was actually built in blockly using the Microsoft MakeCode tool.

```
input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    sprite.change(LedSpriteProperty.X, -0.1)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () {
    sprite.change(LedSpriteProperty.X, 0.1)
})
let sprite: game.LedSprite = null
sprite = game.createSprite(2, 3)
basic.forever(function () {
    if (sprite.get(LedSpriteProperty.X) == 0) {
        music.startMelody(music.builtInMelody(Melodies.Birthday), MelodyOptions.Once)
        basic.showString("liverpool wins")
        sprite.set(LedSpriteProperty.X, 2)
    } else if (sprite.get(LedSpriteProperty.X) == 4) {
        music.startMelody(music.builtInMelody(Melodies.Entertainer), MelodyOptions.Once)
        basic.showString("rb leipzig wins")
        sprite.set(LedSpriteProperty.X, 2)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it was more reliable if I did [game.pause()](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/game/pause) and [game.resume()](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/game/resume) while scrolling the text and playing the music at the end of the game:

```js
input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    sprite.change(LedSpriteProperty.X, -0.1)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () {
    sprite.change(LedSpriteProperty.X, 0.1)
})
let sprite: game.LedSprite = null
sprite = game.createSprite(2, 3)
basic.forever(function () {
    if (sprite.get(LedSpriteProperty.X) == 0) {
        game.pause()
        music.startMelody(music.builtInMelody(Melodies.Birthday), MelodyOptions.Once)
        basic.showString("liverpool wins")
        game.resume()
        sprite.set(LedSpriteProperty.X, 2)
    } else if (sprite.get(LedSpriteProperty.X) == 4) {
        game.pause()
        music.startMelody(music.builtInMelody(Melodies.Entertainer), MelodyOptions.Once)
        basic.showString("rb leipzig wins")
        game.resume()
        sprite.set(LedSpriteProperty.X, 2)
    }
})
```

You can also take a look at the following version of the game that does not use the game rendering engine https://makecode.microbit.org/projects/tug-of-led to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated, ran several times on device without a hitch.  Looks like it’s fixed.  Many thanks!